# Azure SQL LTR Backup - protection against logical server deletion

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Can't seem to find any clear information about the following: will the LTR backup of an Azure SQL database be recoverable in the case of a complete SQL logical server deletion (could it be accidental or admin account compromise).

In other words, does the deletion of the whole logical SQL server would also delete the long-term retention backups?

What are you guys doing to protect against such threat? Database sync to another server & database? Scheduled script to backup the database to a .BACPAC file?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187620/restore-azure-sql-database-ltr-back-up-via-the-portal-after-deleting-the-origina

Answer (score 0):

You can mitigate the risk of deletion of the Azure SQL Database logical server in two steps:

1. By giving users the minimum privileges which they must have for their tasks. You can manage permission of users regarding each element using the [Access control (IAM).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal)
2. You can use [Azure Resource Locks](https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2017/10/21/azure-resource-locks-to-avoid-accidental-deletes/) to avoid accidental deletion.